# What are Free SNMP management probes?

Tags: linux, snmp

I have just started to learn SNMP protocols.

My colleague asks me to "understand the use of free SNMP management probes (available on the internet or in distribution supervision packages)".

Unfortunately I have no clear idea of what is he asking for..

I have installed on my Debian snmp and snmpd. 
I have already understood how to make requests using different MIBs (for example `snmpget localhost -v 2c -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9.0` [to monitor cpu, for example])

But I just cannot understand what he means the use of free SNMP management probes... - something I can download ... where? For free? You have to pay normally for these probes?

If I am not completely mistaken, snmp probes are installed on agents to get information from distant machines?

Where can I download these probes?

Or, if you can correct me - that would be great to understand what is required.

Answer (score 4):

"Probe" is not really a proper technical term or designation for a specific function within the SNMP protocols (not that I am aware of). However, it is a common word that in English is often used when discussing systems monitoring.

I believe your colleague is referring to free SNMP based monitoring and management software in general. There are many free and not-free choices. Here are a few popular ones:

- [Cacti](https://www.cacti.net/)
- [Solarwinds NMP](https://www.solarwinds.com/network-performance-monitor)
- [WhatsUpGold](https://www.whatsupgold.com/)

Comment: Is there an index of these? or specific search terms to find them?

Comment: "snmp monitoring tools"?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

The use of the software was an option, but the simplest way was the following:

```
apt update
```

install either

```
apt install nagios-plugins-contrib
```

or

```
apt install monitoring-plugins-basic
```

Enter the directory where probes (well, it's understood now that he was not talking about "probes" but ... **plugins**!) are located e.g.

```
cd /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
```

Choose the plugin and use it, for example:

```
./check_memory
```